# Ansible synchronize data 3 hosts pull one host

Tags: ansible

I wanna synchronize data 3 hosts pull one host
I make this

```
- name: Pull data from master-0 to 3nodes
  synchronize:
    src: /data/backups/
    dest: /root/test/
    mode: pull
  delegate_to: "{{ inventory_hostname in groups['new_percona'] }}"
  when: '"master-0" in inventory_hostname'
```

But it is failed.

```
ERROR! the field 'delegate_to' has an invalid type (<class 'bool'>), and could not be converted to a string type.
```

How can I use inventory_hostname groups variable on delegate_to?

Answer (score 2):

```
delegate_to
```

expects a **string** type for e.g :

```
delegate_to: my.domain.com
# or
delegate_to: 10.20.230.4
```

as for your provided code snippet, the following:

```
"{{ inventory_hostname in groups['new_percona'] }}" # --> return a boolean
```

that's why you have the 'ERROR'.

As for your question, you could lookup your filtered-out host ('when' usage) vars as follows :

```
{{ hostvars['abc.example.com']['your_var'] }}
# or
hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_ssh_host
```

Ref:

- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html
- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html

Comment: Thank you for helping! It looks like just allow single host. How to operate 3 hosts to pull data from 1 host  at the same time by synchronize module?

Comment: Please note "By default, Ansible runs in parallel against all the hosts in the pattern you set in the hosts". So, your task is actually running in parallel on the target hosts if the config. is not tweeked. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html